# Microsoft Dynamis plugin

Tags: crm

How is life...
I'm new to Microsof Dynamics...

Can anyone tell me why this code work OK for the account number and do nothing for the revenu... won't write the value in the field ???

```
using System;

// Microsoft Dynamics CRM namespace(s)
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

namespace Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples
{
    public class accountManager : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context =  Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));      

        // The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            switch(entity.LogicalName)
            {

                case "account":

                    int accountNumber;
                    accountNumber = 100;
                    entity.Attributes.Add("accountnumber", accountNumber.ToString());

                    int accountRevenu;
                    accountRevenu = 1000;
                    entity.Attributes.Add("revenue", accountRevenu.ToString());

                    break;
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

}

Best Regards
Steph

Comment: don't use `entity.Attributes.Add("accountnumber", value)`, just use `entity["accountnumber"] = value`

Answer (score 2):

Revenue is "currency" field so you should try using following code:

```
entity["revenue"] = new Money(1000);
```